# how to get use getServiceLocator in Model?

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm trying to create a Model to connect to DB but i need to use a adapter. I'm trying to use `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('AdapterDb');`, works fine in a controller but not in a model.

Comment: create singletone - use everywhere you need (but it can be not best solution)

Comment: I really wish I could down-vote the above comment, **please** don't create singletons!

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your Model name is `DBConnect` in `Auth` Module.

So it is placed in folder path `Auth\Model\DBConnect`.

In `Auth` module's `Module.php`, you must be having a `getServiceConfig` function defined.
If not then find about that first. 
This is a function where you register the services, inject any dependencies, etc.

Register your Model here and inject the required `AdapterDb` dependency -

```
namespace Auth;

use Auth\Model\DBConnect;

class Module {

    ....
    .....

    public function getServiceConfig() {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                .... 
                .....

                'Auth\Model\DBConnect' => function($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $model = new DBConnect();
                    $model->setDbAdapter($dbAdapter);
                    return $model;
                },
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Here `setDbAdapter` function is used to set the value, so there should be a function available in the Model.

In DBConnect Model -

```
namespace Auth\Model;

class DBConnect {

    ...
    ....

    protected $_dbAdapter;

    public function setDbAdapter($dbAdapter) {
        $this->_dbAdapter = $dbAdapter;
    }

    public function getDbAdapter() {
        return $this->_dbAdapter;
    }

    ......
}
```

Now use `$this->getDbAdapter()` to get the Adapter you need.

I know its not the best solution. It works just fine.

I hope it helps someone.

Comment: +1 for a good answer and investing more time than the OP did in their question